# How to boost longer ngrams in solr?

Tags: search, solr

I use following filter in the schema.xml:

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="4" maxGramSize="15" side="front"/>
```

How can I boost the longer ngrams? For example, when I search for "bookpage", a document which contains "bookpage" should be rated a lot higher than a document with only "book".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a way to dynamically boost based on term length (i.e., with a Function Query operator). I suspect there isn't one.

That said, I often want to approximate the logic you're looking for: longer term matches deserve a higher semantic weight.

Most commonly, I will index the text value into two different fields. One is a minimally-processed text field without ngrams. The other is similar, but also processed with ngrams.

Here are some sample excerpts of a schema that I have used in this fashion. For searches against this schema, I would boost the `text` field heavily over the `text_ngram`. Thus any matches against the `text` field would greatly influence the relevancy, while matches against `text_ngram` can still pick up perhaps-relevant results as well.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema name="Sunspot Customized NZ" version="1.0">
  <types>

    <!--
      A text type with minimal text processing, for the greatest semantic
      value in a term match. Boost this field heavily.
    -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!--
      Looser matches with NGram processing for substrings of terms and synonyms
    -->
    <fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="6" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- other stuff -->

  </types>
  <fields>

    <!-- id, other scalar values -->

    <!-- catch-all for the text and text_ngram types -->
    <field name="text"       stored="false" type="text"        multiValued="true"  indexed="true" />
    <field name="text_ngram" stored="false" type="text_ngram"  multiValued="true"  indexed="true" />

    <!-- various dynamicField definitions -->

    <!-- sample dynamicField definitions for text and text_ngram -->
    <dynamicField name="*_text"   type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />
    <dynamicField name="*_text_ngram"   type="text_ngram" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" />

  </fields>

  <!-- copy text fields into my text and text_ngram catch-all fields -->
  <copyField source="*_text"  dest="text" />
  <copyField source="*_text"  dest="text_ngram" />

</schema>
```

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but you could use a similar approach.

For example, create a small collection of intermediate NGram-processed field types -- say, of length 1-3, 4-6, 7-9 -- and give them increased boosts accordingly.

Comment: wow, thank you very much for this approach, didn't think about indexing it multiple times :) How did you come up with this solution?

Comment: I don't really remember the first time I used this technique — I feel like it's a pretty common approach in Solr. The `copyField` directive is a pretty strong hint to this effect. I often think of exact term matches as having the strongest semantic worth, where synonyms, ngrams, stemming etc are all various approaches to "expand" the search results in case of a miss on the exact terms.