# While searching with sunspot_rails on Solr, how can I boost whole word matching over partial word matching?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I am using `sunspot_rails` to submit queries to a `Solr` instance. Everything works ok, but I want to order my results with the following criteria: I want to take first the documents where the matching term appears as word rather than as part of a word.

Hence, if I have the two documents:

1) Solr searching with Solr is fantastic

and

2) Solr is very good to support search with free text

and the term I am looking for is : `search`, then

I want to take both documents in the results, but I want document (2) to appear first.

I have tried `order_by :score, :desc` but it does not seem to be working. Unless I find a way to tell how the "score" is calculated.

Thanks in advance
Panayotis

Comment: i don't know if it works with sunspot, but lucene's query syntax allows searching `search~1` for exact match. Other than that, i guess that you'll have to mess with solr filters / tokenizers to prevent stemming, but i'm not sure how.

Comment: possible solution with solr, you have to adapt it for sunspot : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2630879/solr-exact-word-search. Sunspot's wiki explains how to fiddle with filters / tokenizers : https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Advanced-Fulltext-Search-Configuration

Answer (score 3):

You would need to maintain two fields with Solr.
One with the Original value and other with the analyzed value.e.g. `text_org and text (which is analyzed)`
Then you can adjust the boost accordingly, boosting the original field value over the analyzed one e.g. `text_org^2 text^1`
Remember if it matches the original, it will also match the analyzed text or the effect for the exact whole word match is more then the normal match.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on Jayendra's answer a bit, you should index into two separate fields.

Here's an example schema.xml excerpt for Sunspot, from my answer to an earlier question: [How to boost longer ngrams in solr?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8142137/154694)

```
<schema>
  <types>

    <!--
      A text type with minimal text processing, for the greatest semantic
      value in a term match. Boost this field heavily.
    -->
    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!--
      Looser matches with NGram processing for substrings of terms and synonyms
    -->
    <fieldType name="text_ngram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
        <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true" />
        <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="6" side="front" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <!-- other stuff -->

  </types>
  <fields>

    <!-- other fields; refer to *_text -->

    <dynamicField name="*_ngram" type="text_ngram" ... />

  </fields>
</schema>
```

In your `searchable` block, you can use the `:as` option to specify the fieldname:

```
searchable do 

  text :title
  text :title, :as => :title_ngram

  # ...

end
```

Comment: I did similar configs in schema.xml. and used `text :title_ngram, :as => :title_ngram do :title end` But I'm getting zero results. Any Idea, what could be the problem? It would be really good help.